# Cannot install IIS on the azure virtual machines

Tags: azure, azure-vm

When following the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-ssl-portal (using Free Trial as subcription) I always fail for the error

```
ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailed
ErrorMessage:  The client '<mai e-mail address>' with object id'xxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write' over scope '/subscriptions/yyy/resourceGroups/myResourceGroupAG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVM/extensions/IIS' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
ErrorTarget:
StatusCode: 403
ReasonPhrase: Forbidden
OperationID : zzz
```

When runnig the command

```
Set-AzVMExtension `>>   -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroupAG `
>>   -ExtensionName IIS `
>>   -VMName myVM `
>>   -Publisher Microsoft.Compute `
>>   -ExtensionType CustomScriptExtension `
>>   -TypeHandlerVersion 1.4 `
>>   -SettingString '{"commandToExecute":"powershell Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server; powershell Add-Content -Path \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Default.htm\" -Value $($env:computername)"}' `
>>   -Location 'West US 2'
```

According to the portal Access control I (JM in the picture) should have role Virtual machine Contributor, but it doesn't help.

[image]

Comment: RDP to the VM and Enable IIS from using windows feature

Comment: @Aatif Akhter What do you mean by "RDP to The VM" ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/connect-logon

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT got your point, but I cannot test it right now as my free trial outdated meanwile working with log4j fixes...

Comment: Hello @Jaana, Since this is working for me in this way .you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tried with same PowerShell script command it is perfectly working for me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can try to run `Disconnect-AzAccount` and `Clear-AzContext` as a solution, so that the context of all the user are deleted and after that you can again login to azure from powershell by `Connect-Azaccount`.

The Owner Access in Subscription level is sufficient to perform the operation that you are trying to perform so , Separately giving the Virtual Machine Contributor Role is not required.

OR

**To workaround this issue you can manually install IIS server .**

**Step 1**: Login to you VM.

**Step 2** : Manage->Add role and feature
[image]

**Step 3** : Select Webserver IIS -> Next->Install

[image]